# How to set shell output to a particular mode?

Tags: emacs, grep

I'm starting to use shell-mode more often in emacs and what I'd really like is for grep output and other grep-like-output (gcc, etc) to recognize source code line references and allow me to jump to source lines in the output. Is there a way to apply grep-mode to a single Output Group?

Answer (score 1):

No, emacs modes are whole-buffer.

However, you can narrow to the last output, turn on `grep-mode`, and `widen` and restore `comint-mode` when done.

Nevertheless, the `grep` command (and `compile` for `gcc`) are more than adequate; use them instead of running `gcc` and `grep` in the `*shell*` buffer.